# Jquery addClass/removeClass works in browser but not on iPhone

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have a somewhat unique little filter I built. It's a series of "status" buttons. Clicking each button subsets a list. I send the button id/status via ajax, search for matching combinations, return a json list of values to show. On ajax.success I hide all rows, then show the rows from the json response. It works great in my browser. But does not work on my phone. 
Here is the jquery portion...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pstat").click(function(){
        var id = this.id;
        $("#" + id).toggleClass('btn-primary');

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            url: '/properties/active',
            data: ({data:id}),
            success: function (response){
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                $("tbody tr").addClass("hidden");
                $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                    $("." + value).removeClass("hidden");
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The first portion of the script toggles the buttons so I can tell which ones are selected. State is saved in session.

On success... hide all rows...then for each of the items in the response...remove the hidden class.

the returned values are a concatenated pair of values that match the classes. 
ie class="Closed Pending"

Like I said, works great in Chrome & FF, but won't even execute the initial add hidden class when the page is loaded on my phone.

Site is in Cakephp 2.3
Jquery 1.11 is successfully loaded. 
I am using BootstrapCake plugin. 
Site is a private crm otherwise I'd provide a url.

Any idea where to start looking?

Answer (score 0):

As a start, I would take some steps to verify that your `success` callback is definitely getting called on the iPhone:

1) Add a `console.log` - or even an alert if you don't have a handy way to view a console via an iPhone setup - to check you're receiving a response in your `success` callback:

```
success: function (response){
    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(obj);
    // rest of your code
}
```

2) Add an `error` callback function to double-check the Ajax request via the iPhone isn't failing for some reason or other:

```
success: function (response) {
    ...
},
error: function() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

I appreciate this answer might be a little late to the party, but if not then hopefully it'll give you something useful to go on.